# Is there a script that can be written in google sheets that will "copy to clipboard"?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a sheet that other co-workers will copy and paste from often. I want to make this faster and easier by adding a button via insert> drawing, and then assigning the drawing a script that will copy the content of a certain cell. You can assign a script to the button seen in my image below, but I'm not experienced enough to write a script to copy the cell. In this case, it would be copying the text of cell C4 to the clipboard so it can be pasted elsewhere. Is this possible? If so, what is the script that will do this?

[image: Copy Button inserted]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29686324/copy-to-clipboard-function-in-google-sheets

Comment: teach your co-workers the magic of **CTRL+C** / **CTRL+V** :)

Comment: Apps Script code doesn't execute in your browser, so it has no access to the browser clipboard.

Comment: I had read that previous thread about this before, but it was a while ago and I wondered if it had changed. Thanks for your input. We do use CTR+C/V often but I just like the idea of making things even more automated and smarter.